# What exactly does disablewebsecurity do when used with a <webview> or Chrome/Chromium?

Tags: google-chrome, webview, chromium, electron, webviewchromium

I'm interested in understanding exactly what the attribute `disablewebsecurity` does when used with a webview element like this: `<webview src=www.somesite.com disablewebsecurity>`

I have an electron app that is a wrapper around a web app, and were using `<webview>` elements to iframe pages.

However, I want to completely understand what I'm exposing my application to wrt using the `disablewebsecurity` flag.

I know that this allows CORS requests and ignores the X-FRAME-OPTIONS header, but what else does it do? Im particularly curious about its access to cookie namespaces.

Also, is this attribute the same as opening Chrome/Chromium with the command line flag `--disable-web-security`?

Any insight is appreciated (I couldn't find it documented anywhere).

Thanks!